# How can I use a MediaRecorder object in an Angular2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webrtc, mediarecorder-api

I'm building a small Angular2 app and I'm trying to use a MediaRecorder object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) like so:

```
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
```

However, TypeScript is telling me it cannot find name 'MediaRecorder'. I'm guessing this is down to my TypeScript configuration which I pulled directly from the QuickStart guide (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html). The configuration looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

I've seen various configurations around the web that include "target: es6" or "lib: es6" and also ones with modules other that "commonjs" but I'm new to this so I'm not really sure what is going on. When I've tried updating these values I get more errors.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your compiler doesn't know anything about the `MediaRecorder` object.

Simply declare it like this:

```
declare var MediaRecorder: any;
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't allow you to declare a variable of type `MediaRecorder`. Using `declare class Mediarecorder {}` in turn doesn't allow accessing any of a media recorder's properties. The solution, therefore, really is to declare the full typings as suggested by Tiberiu.

Answer (score 80):

You can now add types for `MediaRecorder` even easier, just install them through npm.

```
npm install -D @types/dom-mediacapture-record
```

This will load the latest type definitions from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). They will automatically work, no extra steps.
If you have any improvements for the typings feel free to contribute them to DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: This answer says "This will automatically work, no extra steps" but this was not the case for me. Check @jyl087's answer below AND the comment to it about rootTypes

Comment: Types are only necessary during the development, therefore you should use the `-D` parameter with the command. You don't want to install the types on the server.

Comment: @vdegenne You're right, added the -D parameter to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: As much as I agree with the types beeing a npm package, the rule should apply for third parties not standard dom Apis. Types should come frome typescript itself via the libs property of the tsconfig.

Answer (score 29):

I landed on this page with the same problem and installed the dom-mediacapture-record module, but was still having problems. After much hair pulling, I found out why MediaRecorder was still not being found.

My app had an autogenerated "tsconfig.app.json" file with the following line:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "types": ["node"]
  ... }
```

I realized that "types" was blocking the inclusion of the dom-mediacapture-record module! It should be changed to:

```
"types": ["node", "dom-mediacapture-record"]
```

Thought I'd pass that tidbit along to save others from hours of hair pulling.

Comment: Important to take special note that this is the tsconfig.app.json file in the app module that needs to be configured, rather than the tsconfig.json in the base folder. Ensure dom-mediacapture-record is in the types array and that the     "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"] is set.

Answer (score 26):

Until `MediaRecorer` lands in Typescript dom.lib `any` suffices for lazy people. But it evicts the whole point of TypeScript.

So why not an almost full blown type declaration  :

Place this in an ambient declaration file, ex: `index.d.ts`

```
declare interface MediaRecorderErrorEvent extends Event {
    name: string;
}

declare interface MediaRecorderDataAvailableEvent extends Event {
    data : any;
}

interface MediaRecorderEventMap {
    'dataavailable': MediaRecorderDataAvailableEvent;
    'error': MediaRecorderErrorEvent ;
    'pause': Event;
    'resume': Event;
    'start': Event;
    'stop': Event;
    'warning': MediaRecorderErrorEvent ;
}


declare class MediaRecorder extends EventTarget {

    readonly mimeType: string;
    readonly state: 'inactive' | 'recording' | 'paused';
    readonly stream: MediaStream;
    ignoreMutedMedia: boolean;
    videoBitsPerSecond: number;
    audioBitsPerSecond: number;

    ondataavailable: (event : MediaRecorderDataAvailableEvent) => void;
    onerror: (event: MediaRecorderErrorEvent) => void;
    onpause: () => void;
    onresume: () => void;
    onstart: () => void;
    onstop: () => void;

    constructor(stream: MediaStream);

    start();

    stop();

    resume();

    pause();

    isTypeSupported(type: string): boolean;

    requestData();


    addEventListener<K extends keyof MediaRecorderEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MediaStream, ev: MediaRecorderEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;

    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;

    removeEventListener<K extends keyof MediaRecorderEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MediaStream, ev: MediaRecorderEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;

    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;

}
```

And yes type competition works:

[image: InteliJ Type AutoComplete]

### TIP

Usually I configure in `tsconfig.json` a folder where I keep all `js`es or `APIs` that have no typedef

For example for a project layout like this

```
project/
  @types <- a folder where I define my types 
    index.d.ts
  src
    ...
  ...
  tsconfig.json
```

I write in `tsconfig.json` something like this :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./@types"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: I set this up exactly as you described - by adding a @types directory and a corresponding typeRoots entry in tsconfig.json - and still I am getting `ERROR in src/app/modals/record/record.component.ts(179,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder'.` Is there perhaps some additional step I am missing?

Comment: `*.d.ts` extension?

Comment: Yes, the file has a .d.ts extension.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a closer look. Maybe you have a multiple tsconfig.json files, at least that is the case for a project bootstraped with angular-cli: https://github.com/stackblitz/angular-cli-template/blob/485e1f099cf4caa616eb753ec17014c8ffc5507e/.angular-cli.json#L18 can you check that ?

typeRoutes are described here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: As well if you have configured `baseURL`  than the modules will be resolve in regards to that path. You can trace that with `--traceResolution` flag when runing `tsc -p $PROJECT_DIR --traceResolution`

Comment: And of course if the configuration doesn't work for you you can hint the compiler the exact path of an ambient declaration with a triple slash directive `/// <reference path="..." />` in a ts file

Comment: I followed this solution, adding the index.d.ts file in a root @types folder, adding it to typeRoots, etc. However, on using 'new MediaRecorder(stream),' I get the error "Type 'MediaRecorder' has no construct signatures." Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

> You can now add types for MediaRecorder even easier, just install them through npm.

`npm install @types/dom-mediacapture-record`

> This will load the latest type definitions from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). They will automatically work, no extra steps. If you have any improvements for the typings feel free to contribute them to DefinitelyTyped.

That solution proposed by Elias Meire is the best for me. But indeed I needed some extra steps to make it work. As stated in this issue on github https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11420#issuecomment-341625253, you have to reference it to use it with this line:

```
/// <reference types="@types/dom-mediacapture-record" />
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear for me... Where should I place this directive `/// <reference types="@types/dom-mediacapture-record" />` ?

Comment: Have you tried placing it where you have to use it?

Comment: You should put `/// <reference types="@types/dom-mediacapture-record" />` as the first line on your page.

Answer (score 8):

I installed @types/dom-mediacapture-record in Angular 9 app but the only thing that resolved this issue for me was tweaking `tsconfig.app.json`
types:  "types": ["node", "dom-mediacapture-record"].

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node", "dom-mediacapture-record"]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `npm install -D @types/dom-mediacapture-record` is enough, don't modify tsconfig.json at all, no types no ///reference no typeRoots is neccesary (and those are rarely needed for anything in general....