# MediaRecorder.ondataavailable with Angular, How can I make the binding work?

Tags: angular

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40112349/6123422), I can use MediaRecorder with angular. But I have a problem with the binding.

Variable:

```
public test: string = "Step1";
```

MediaRecorder:

```
start(){
        this.test = "Step2"
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
        this.mediaRecorder.onstop = (e) => {
            console.log("look i'm the console"); 
            this.test = "Step4";
        }
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
    }

    stop(){
        this.test = "Step3"
        this.mediaRecorder.stop();
    }
```

Html:
Progression: {{test }}

```
<button (click)="start()">Start</button>
<button (click)="stop()">Stop</button>
```

I remove most of my code for the exemple, like this it will be easier to understand.

- I launch the App, I can see **Progression: Step1**
- I click on start, I can see **Progression: Step2**
- I click on stop, I can see **Progression: Step3**,
- Then the event onstop is launch, in the console I can see **look i'm the console**, but Progression is still on Step3 not Step4.

How can I make the binding work correctly in my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', event => {
        console.log("look i'm the console"); 
        this.test = "Step4";
    });
```