# MediaStreamRecorder is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, angular6, mediastream

I'm new to Angular6 and I'm trying to use `MediaStreamRecorder`. I'm definitely doing something wrong when defining `MediaStreamRecorder` because I keep getting the error `TypeError: msr__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.MediaStreamRecorder is not a constructor`. Not sure how or where should I declare and define `MediaStreamRecorder`. Can you help me with this, please?

I have installed `msr` module, and my code looks like this:

```
import { Component,ViewChild, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { LinksService } from 'demo/_services/links.service';
import { Http,Response,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { MediaStreamRecorder} from 'msr';
import { RecordRTC } from 'recordrtc';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-ceva',
  templateUrl: './ceva.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ceva.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: SpeechRecognitionLang,
      useValue: 'en-US',
    },    
    SpeechRecognitionService,
  ],
})
export class CevaComponent { 
  public navigator: any;      
  public MediaStreamRecorder: any;    
  constructor( private http: Http, private service: SpeechRecognitionService, private links: LinksService ) { 
this.record = () => {       
    var browser = <any>navigator;  
    var obj = { audio: true, video:false };
    browser.getUserMedia = (browser.getUserMedia || browser.webkitGetUserMedia || browser.mozGetUserMedia || browser.msGetUserMedia);     
    browser.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(obj).then(stream => {  
        var source = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);      
        var config= { ... }  
        var recorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream, config);
        recorder.record();
        recorder.stop(function(blob) {     
            var blob = recorder.blob;
            console.log(blob);           
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: is this library https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder ?

Comment: I think so. I am not sure whether this API is pretty much the same thing or derived: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder

Comment: you are trying to reference plain browser components into angular typescript. look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051818/how-can-i-use-a-mediarecorder-object-in-an-angular2-application

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful :)

Comment: when you solve please post the solution :)

Comment: ok. I am still working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051818/how-can-i-use-a-mediarecorder-object-in-an-angular2-application) suggested, the solution to me was that in `typings.d.ts` file to add the following declarations:

```
declare interface MediaRecorderErrorEvent extends Event {
  name: string;
}

declare interface MediaRecorderDataAvailableEvent extends Event {
  data : any;
}

interface MediaRecorderEventMap {
  'dataavailable': MediaRecorderDataAvailableEvent;
  'error': MediaRecorderErrorEvent ;
  'pause': Event;
  'resume': Event;
  'start': Event;
  'stop': Event;
  'warning': MediaRecorderErrorEvent ;
}


declare class MediaRecorder extends EventTarget {

  readonly mimeType: string;
  // readonly MimeType: 'audio/wav';
  readonly state: 'inactive' | 'recording' | 'paused';
  readonly stream: MediaStream;
  ignoreMutedMedia: boolean;
  videoBitsPerSecond: number;
  audioBitsPerSecond: number;

  ondataavailable: (event : MediaRecorderDataAvailableEvent) => void;
  onerror: (event: MediaRecorderErrorEvent) => void;
  onpause: () => void;
  onresume: () => void;
  onstart: () => void;
  onstop: () => void;

  constructor(stream: MediaStream);

  start();

  stop();

  resume();

  pause();

  isTypeSupported(type: string): boolean;

  requestData();


  addEventListener<K extends keyof MediaRecorderEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MediaStream, ev: MediaRecorderEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;

  addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;

  removeEventListener<K extends keyof MediaRecorderEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MediaStream, ev: MediaRecorderEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;

  removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
```

And in my component, I was able to use `var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);` without any other declarations. Thank you, @firegloves , for the link to this post and thank you, @Tiberiu C. for the answer! It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -D @types/dom-mediacapture-record
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with pure JS and React and removing the following line "fixed" the problem:

`window.MediaRecorder = require('audio-recorder-polyfill');`