# Protractor unit tests Angular does not work with MediaRecorder

Tags: angular, protractor, mediarecorder

I have an Angular 11 project and I have unit tests implemented. Recently, I added a MediaRecorder in the project, and none of the tests run anymore. The tests "compilation" throws the following exception: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder'.`.

**Note** that the project itself compiles, but it does not in the tests context. Is there any possible solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To successfully compile an Angular project that uses MediaRecorder, I used the answer from the following question ([media recorder with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051818/how-can-i-use-a-mediarecorder-object-in-an-angular2-application)):

> npm install -D @types/dom-mediacapture-record

This solution helps, compiling the project, but tests cannot run because the MediaRecorder is still missing for tests. My solution was to use one of the other solutions suggested in the same question:

> "compilerOptions": {...
> "types": ["node", "dom-mediacapture-record"]...
> }

But in this case, I configure the `tsconfig.spec.json` (responsible for tests), INSTEAD OF `tsconfig.app.json`